# Shared folder between Host and Guest in VM player

Tags: networking, network-shares, vmware-player, shared-folders

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Home Basic and I installed Ubuntu in VM player. Now I want to share folders and files between Windows and Ubuntu. How can share a folder or file?

Answer (score 1):

You create a shared folder like any other.

Then on Ubuntu, you can access it over the network `\\hostname\SharedFolderName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup shared folders on the VMWare level.  Go to VM -> Settings -> options - Shared Folders.  This is the easiest way to setup sharing between the host and VM.

Here is the link to the [VMWare documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html) on how to setup shared folders as well.