# Sharing folders between vm and host machine

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine

Trying to use VMware player and VMware workstation.

Host is Windows 7 and VM is Ubuntu 12.10

I have vmtools installed on the vm and went into the settings for the vm to add the folders I want as shared. I also have them shared through Windows anyway but when I go to /mft there is no hgfs or anything like that.

I've looked at these other super user posts, but it doesn't work.

[This one](https://superuser.com/questions/370144/shared-folder-between-host-and-guest-in-vm-player)

[aaaand this one](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html)

[aaaaaaaaaaand this one](https://superuser.com/questions/513270/shared-folder-between-win7-host-and-ubuntu-guest)

[also this one](https://superuser.com/questions/527963/how-to-allow-nginx-in-guest-vm-access-shared-folders-in-host-os)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this before. This is what I did to resolve it.

1. Deleted the Shared Folder in Virtual Machine Settings/Options
2. Updated VmWare Tools on the Guest VM
3. Recreated the Shared Folders
4. Edited host path to point to correct location